# How add new enums in typedef enum in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, enums, typedef

I need help, i have typedef enum:

```
typedef enum category
{
    All, 
    category1,
    category2,
    category3,
    category4,
} category;
```

Can I add new enums in category, for example:

```
typedef enum category
{
    All, 
    category1,
    category2,
    category3,
    category4,
    category5,
    category6,
    category7,
} category;
```

Comment: Do you mean to support a new version of your app, or to add new options for a subclass or something?

Comment: @jrturton, yes, to support a new version app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just add them. You aren't changing the values of the existing ones or changing the order, so any storage of these values in your previous version will be unaffected.

If you want to update the list at runtime, as suggested in your comments, then this isn't possible and an enum is the wrong structure to be using. An enum isn't much more than a fancy list of constants. You would need a different solution.

Comment: ok, thank's, but how can I add to the existing typedef, because is not entirely new version my app. names categories taken from the server and need add to the existing

Comment: I don't understand. I thought you were asking if it was OK to add new entries to an enum, which it is. Are you saying you want to update the enum at runtime based on something you are downloading?